# PHP fopen not working

Tags: php, file

I just can't figure this out, I keep getting Unable To Create Group.

What I'm attempting to do is you submit a forum, and it creates a file with some info in it. If the group name already exist(the file) then tell them that. Though I keep getting as I stated "Unable To Create Group" as my die message.

This is the PHP part:

```
<?php
if($_POST['ownername'] && $_POST['groupname']){

$ownername = htmlspecialchars($_POST["ownername"]);
$groupname = htmlspecialchars($_POST["groupname"]);

echo 'Owner is ' . $ownername . ' and the group is ' . $groupname;
$groupfile = '/groups/' . $groupname . '.txt';

if(file_exists($groupfile) == false){
    $newgroup = fopen($groupfile, 'w') or die("Unable to create group");
    $txt = "Users:" . $ownername;
    fwrite($newgroup, $txt);
    fclose($myfile);
    echo "<font style='color:green'>The group has been created! You may access it <a href='chat.php?group=" . $groupname . "'>here</a></font>";
} else {
    echo "<font style='color:red'>The group name is taken, please use another name or wait for it to be released</font>";
}
}
?>
```

Then this is my HTML part:

```
<form action=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?> method="post">
<input type="text" name="ownername" placeholder="Username"/>
<input type="text" name="groupname" placeholder="Group Name"/>
<input type="submit" value="Create"/>
</form>
```

Any and all help is appreciated, thank you very much!

Comment: What are the file permissions of the file? Does is_writable() return true for the file?

Comment: I think you make a mistake with absolute path. You want to write to a root folder of server or site?

Comment: Do you actually have the file in /groups/... on your file system? Or is it a path from your webroot direcotry?

Comment: @vvanadiam I'll try playing with the file location

Answer (score 0):

If the filename doesn't exist yet, use `'x'` instead of `'w'` to create a file and allow writing into.

```
$newgroup = fopen($groupfile, 'x');
```

Comment: @Master: the same error message (from `die`)? Do you have permissions to dir where you want to create new file? Due to the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) it should work. Manual says: 'x' - _Create and open for writing only_